# Docker commands via php shell_exec

Tags: php, shell, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying run command from my index.php:

```
$output = shell_exec('docker images');
```

and then output results,

or run new container the same way:

```
$output = shell_exec('docker run hello-world');
```

It seems that I could not run ANY docker cmd via php.

How do it properly?

Comment: Are you running PHP outside of the container?

Comment: Yes. I try run it from web browser on host.

Comment: What is in your container? Is it a web server? If so, there'd be no way to see output in the browser because of port conflicts amongst other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
vi rd.php
```

Put this content in rd.php file

```
<?php 
$output = shell_exec('RET=`docker run hello-world`;echo $RET');
echo $output;
```

Now you can run

```
php rd.php
```

You can view the result :

```
Hello from Docker. This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly. To generate this message, Docker took the following steps: 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon. 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub. (Assuming it was not already locally available.) 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the executable that produces the output you are currently reading. 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it to your terminal. To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with: $ docker run -it ubuntu bash For more examples and ideas, visit: http://docs.docker.com/userguide/
```

That's all !

I hope this help you

Comment: Yes, it works but only if I run it within console.
When I'm trying to run it in my browser, I cannot see results from output.

Comment: Perhaps there is a security issue running this inside a WEB Page

Comment: I've almost found the solution. I modified file sudoers (sudo visudo), by adding at the end: www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL. PHP now runs my docker commands.
I know is dangerous, but if I change it to: 
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/php, /usr/bin/php5
It still doesn't working. Some other idea?

(http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115054/php-shell-exec-permission-on-linux-ubuntu)

Comment: my var/log/apache2/error.log contains:
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Answer (score 4):

I did the following to get this working:

1. Created a php file called *index.php* on */var/www/html/* with this content:

   ```
   <?php
       echo '<pre>';
       $content = system('sudo docker images', $ret);
       echo '</pre>';
   ?>
   ```
2. Edited sudoers file with *visudo*, adding the following line at the end:

   ```
   www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/docker
   ```
3. Checked `http://localhost/index.php` and it worked!

[image]

You can even build and run containers with this, hope it works for you.